# Import ReactNative libraries into a NativeScript application

Tags: nativescript, react-native

I have some Android development experience along with React.js. I'm working on a new mobile project and I haven't been sold entirely on either framework yet.

I'm thinking about using the NativeScript framework for its maturity and because it has more libraries with the functionality that I need but I'd like to design my views in a manner similar to ReactJS. I know I could write my own modules for ReactNative but that would require then I'd have to write modules for both Android and iOS. I'd like to avoid that if I could.

I was thinking about importing the necessary ReactNative libraries into a NativeScript project and then being able to write views in a way similar to ReactNative but still using NativeScript.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your exact question. I did just see an integration between Preact and NativeScript you may be interested in. Take a look here: https://github.com/staydecent/nativescript-preact

I believe that repo is in the early stages, but if enough people want something similar, it'll get worked on faster.

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction.

I'm looking for a way to write application UI's in a manner similar to ReactJS but using the NativeScript framework. My first thoughts were to try and manually insert ReactJS libraries into a NativeScript project but this makes more sense.

I'll edit the question for clarity. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using React Native in NativeScript is not the right approach, either of it are not built to work together and wouldn't work due to architectural reasons. Here is an [NativeScript official comparison](https://www.nativescript.org/faq#is-it-kind-of-like-react-native?) of these two.

Both are built for solving same problem (building native apps using JS, without webview hybrid app approach) by trans-compiling XML based view layer(which both these framework has its own syntax and so cant be shared) to build Native UI.

Said that view layer has its own syntax for both and cant be shared, **model and controller layer cant be shared as well**, due to the fact that NativeScript has few things [packed as part of the application package](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-android-application-package-size-revealed), like JavaScript runtime, c++ and Java API layer which helps in exposing all the Native API without the need for any explicit native API wrapper we have in ReactNative.

React Native have platform specific UI components as well as hardware capabilities, which is not the case with NativeScript. Offcouse, that comes with the cost of a fatter app package size(50+MB) compared to <10MB for ReactNative. More on [ReactNative vs NativeScript comparison here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47997535/1057093).